# Setting os.environ variables in wsgi causes maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to pass Apache variables into my environment for a Django application running on AWS Ubuntu. I read instructions for how to do that [here](http://ericplumb.com/blog/passing-apache-environment-variables-to-django-via-mod_wsgi.html). I set an environment variable in my Apache config like this:

```
SetEnv EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD foobar
```

Then, I used this loop in my wsgi.py file:

```
env_variables_to_pass = ['EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD']
def application(environ, start_response):
    # pass the WSGI environment variables on through to os.environ
    for var in env_variables_to_pass:
        os.environ[var] = environ.get(var, '')
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

The problem is, when I hit my application, I get the following strange error:

```
os.environ[var] = environ.get(var, '')
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? Some other questions I read suggested I upgrade to Python 2.7.5, but I'm using 2.7.6. I'm also using Django 1.6.8

Comment: Just a warning that in general the setting of os.environ on a per request basis from values in the WSGI environ dictionary is regarded as bad practice. Part of the reason is that if you have a setup with multiple hosted WSGI application in the same process, even in different sub interpreters, and the different applications use different values for the variables, they have the potential to stomp on and interfere with each other in a multithreaded configuration.